# Django compress + static with amazon s3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

I have a django application with the following architecture:

```
skeleton/
   assets/
       sass/
   static/
       css/
   templates/
       base.html
   settings/
       common.py
       dev.py
       prod.py
apps/
    views.py
    // ...
```

I have a `gulpfile.js` script that compile all the sass into `skeleton/static/css/desktop.css`, and I have in my template `skeleton/templates/base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load compress staticfiles %}
{% block css %}
    {% compress css %}
        <link href="{% static "css/desktop.css" %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endcompress %}
{% endblock %}
</head>
...
```

---

My settings are:

```
# common.py
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'compressor',
    ...
)
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'CACHE'
```

This file is imported by `prod` and `dev`:

```
# prod.py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'apps.core.storage.CachedS3BotoStorage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

and

```
# dev.py
DEBUG = True
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```

I have followed the [using-staticfiles guide](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote-storages/#using-staticfiles) and implemented the `CachedS3BotoStorage` (the code is exactly the same).

Locally it works fine, but as soon as I try to push it to heroku the compilation fails:

> CommandError: An error occurred during rendering skeleton/templates/base.html: 'https://XXX.amazonaws.com/css/desktop.css' isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('https://XXX.amazonaws.com/') and can't be compressed

---

Where I'm lost, is that the file `https://XXX.amazonaws.com/css/desktop.css` exists (i.e. if I try to access it directly I got the file back), but somehow the compress statement does not work.

I thought that adding the `CachedS3BotoStorage` file storage would help but apparently it does not.

---

What should I do to solve this?

**Note:** I have included only the minimal amount of code/config to hopefully give context, but if anything else make sense I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `{% compress %}` tags in your template.

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54605801) answer helpful.